# Get 2 MSB digits from a decimal number in c

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I wonder is there anyway to get the first 2 most significant bits of a binary number version of a decimal number without converting it to actually binary number. For example, I want to get "00" from 5 which is "00101" in binary. Does c supports this binary conversion in an easy way? Does c support shifting and bit masking etc?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to examine a binary string?  Then the 2 MSB would the first two characters.  If it is a binary number, then it is even easier.  Yes C does have support for shifting and bit masking.  Read up on the <<, >>, &, |, ^ and ~ operators for details.

Comment: *The first 2 bits are `00`*. Which 5-bit processor are you using? You might just as well say that `5` in binary is `0101` so the first two bits are `01`. But broadly, "yes you can".

Comment: *without converting it to actually binary number*. Please understand that numbers *are* typically stored in binary. It's decimal you have to convert.

Comment: I am using it for converting virtual memory address to phsiycal memory address actually. So I have to convert it to binary number and then use these operators, right?

Comment: Assuming you want to select the 2 most significant binary digits from a 32 bit unsigned integer, use: `y = x >>30;`

Comment: How is the decimal number stored? You're going to have a hard time unless you convert it to binary (or at least to something binary-friendly like octal or hex).

Comment: OP gave  "binary number", "decimal number" and examples with strings like  `"00"` and `"00101"`.  This is all unclear.  Please re-phrase with more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does!

So to get the first 2 bits from an 8-bit number we need to mask your current number.
We can do this:

```
some_number = some_number & 0xC0;
some_number &= 0xC0; // This does the same thing with a different syntax
```

So what we're doing here is performing a bitwise AND with the value `0xC0`, converting `0xC0` to binary gives us `1100 0000`. So when we AND this value with `some_number` we get ONLY the top 2 bits as every other value in the number is `0` and so produces a `0` whenever we AND it with anything else.

For numbers larger than 8-bit all we have to do is increase the length of our mask. 
Here's another example say we want the top 2 bits of a 32 bit integer

```
some_number = some_number & 0xC00000
```